# printing a value using selenium python find_elements_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to print a variable (rel="3380.80") value using selenium python.

here is my approach `tree = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[11]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/rel")`

print(tree)

```
<div id="nsecp" class="inprice1 nsecp" rel="3380.80" data-numberanimate-value="3,380.80" data-numberanimate-characterheight="65" data-numberanimate-characterwidth="31" data-numberanimate-animationtimes="[10,0,10]" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 65px;"><div data-numberanimate-pos="5" style="width: 31px; height: 65px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly ?

Comment: Can't able to print rel value @catalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 1 element there which has rel=3380.00 and it also has id attribute. you can find the element by id and get the attribute rel. Here is the code

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('nsecp')
val = el.get_attribute("rel")
```